# Get reCaptcha value via javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I've added reCaptcha to my site, and when I use it normally in a form everything works great, but now I faced a problem when I tried to read the captcha value via JavaScript or jQuery. I have this HTML code that loads reCaptcha on my page.

```
<div align="center">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=mySecretkey321"></script>
    <noscript>
        <iframe src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=mySecretkey321" height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe><br>
        <textarea id="rcf" name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea>
        <input type="hidden" id="rrf" name="recaptcha_response_field" value="manual_challenge">
    </noscript>
    <input type="button" value="Ok!" id="ok" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg"/>
</div>
```

When I fill in the captcha field and click on a button I want to load the values of **recaptcha_response_field** and **recaptcha_challenge_field** so I can submit them via $.get(); so I've come up with this code:

```
$("#ok").click(function() {
    var res,res2;
    var rcf = document.getElementsByName('recaptcha_challenge_field').value;
    var rrf = document.getElementsByName('recaptcha_response_field').value;
    var url = "go.php?rcf="+ rcf +"&rrf=" + rrf;
    alert(url);
    $.get( url, function( data ) {
      var n = data.indexOf("#");
      res = data.slice(0,n);
      res2 = data.slice(n+1);
    });
});
```

When I click the button I get an alert box with this value:

```
go.php?rcf=undefined&rrf=undefined
```

Basically I can't read those fields and I think that I'm reading the wrong ones. File go.php verifies captcha I just need to pass those two captcha fields to it so it can do all the background work of checking the captcha.

I really don't know how to achieve this and I guess there is a simple solution, but I couldn't find it anywhere so I wanted to ask the community.

Best Regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `document.getElementsByName` function returns a collection of elements, as the name sort of implies - it's elements (with an s - plural). That collection doesn't have a `value` property defined on it, which is why trying to access it returns `undefined`.

If you're sure that there's only ever going to be exactly one (no more and no fewer) elements with those names, you can access the first index in the collection (which is the element you want) and get its value:

```
var rcf = document.getElementsByName('recaptcha_challenge_field')[0].value;
var rrf = document.getElementsByName('recaptcha_response_field')[0].value;
```

Alternatively, you could use jQuery (since you've already loaded it to use it for the AJAX call) to get the values:

```
var rcf = $('[name="recaptcha_challenge_field"]').val();
var rrf = $('[name="recaptcha_response_field"]').val();
```

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with the "document.getElementsByName". It returns an array and arrays don't have the "value" attribute.
I'd rather try with:

```
var rcf = document.getElementsByName('recaptcha_challenge_field')[0].value;
var rrf = document.getElementsByName('recaptcha_response_field')[0].value;
```

if you're just looking for the first element with the specified tag.